# Apache 2.4.10 unable to get the remote host name with Require host

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I have this config in the main apache2.conf file:

```
#restrict access to key store
<Directory "/var/www/sites/siteabc/vr3587/keys”>
 Options FollowSymlinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require host siteabc.com
</Directory>
```

These are my virtual host file directives:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/siteabc/vr3587
ServerName www.siteabc.com
<Directory "/var/www/sites/siteabc/vr3587”>
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
AllowOverride All
order allow,deny
allow from all
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.siteabc.com"
</Directory>
ServerAlias siteabc.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/siteabc_cert.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/siteabc_gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
SSLProtocol +TLSv1.2
```

I need to restrict access to /var/www/sites/siteabc/vr3587/keys except for the host siteabc.com, to protect hls player encryption keys from unauthorized access. With above configuration, no access to /var/www/sites/siteabc/vr3587/keys is allowed at all and the video does not play. If I comment out the lines in my apache2conf file, then unrestricted access is restored. In the no access case, the errors in the apache log are: "reason: unable to get the remote host name" and "authorization result of Require host siteabc.com: denied". The host siteabc.com is PTR enabled (checked with nslookup from server). I can't use Require ip or Require local, because this is an hls player on our site- it needs Require host. Been working for days on this- any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably have a DNS problem. Make sure your DNS is working. Of course you really should just use the IP address that is allowed to access the directory, rather than hostname lookups.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How can I tell if the DNS is configured correctly for apache? If I run nslookup siteabc.com from the command I get the correct response- the PTR is listed. I reversed the DNS resolution order, so now it tries DNS first and the hosts file second, but problem persists. Does the hostname of the whole machine make a difference?

Comment: Did you look it up _on that server_? Because that is what Apache is doing.

Comment: Yes, I did- I looked it up on that server. Can there be some other way that apache is checking DNS?

Comment: The [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html#requiredirectives) state: "This configuration will cause Apache to perform a double reverse DNS lookup on the client IP address, regardless of the setting of the HostnameLookups directive. It will do a reverse DNS lookup on the IP address to find the associated hostname, and then do a forward lookup on the hostname to assure that it matches the original IP address. Only if the forward and reverse DNS are consistent and the hostname matches will access be allowed."

Comment: You really, really should avoid this, and just list the IP addresses of the server(s) that you intend to allow.

Comment: Thanks I wish I could, I agree. But it seems the hls player process is appearing to the server as siteabc.com. I tried to Require the IP and it also did work. Just tried it again, here is the error log: AH01626: authorization result of Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xx: denied, referer: https://www.siteabc.com 
yet the IP is the IP of the server